# quicksand sorting price values low to high / high to low

Tags: jquery, sorting

I'm using quicksand to re order a product list title asc / desc and price asc / desc

For some reason, it's sorting the price like this

10 , 1, 2, 3, 4

or 4, 3, 2, 1, 10

It appears to be sorting on the first digit in the value ?

here's my code...

```
if ( sortLi.hasClass( 'priceAsc' ) ) {

$lis.children().sortElements(function(a, b){
return $(a).find('input[name=price]').val() > $(b).find('input[name=price]').val() ? 1 : -1;
});         

}

if ( sortLi.hasClass( 'priceDesc' ) ) {

$lis.children().sortElements(function(a, b){
return $(a).find('input[name=price]').val() < $(b).find('input[name=price]').val() ? 1 : -1;
});         

}
```

Comment: Looks like it's sorting it alphabetically... i.e. treating the values as text *not* numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val()` gives you a string, so `>` and `<` comparisons are lexographical (not numeric).  Try wrapping the values in `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`.  Make sure to add appropriate error handling as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably comparing strings lexicographically, instead of integers.

Try converting everything to number before comparing. Something like this:

```
if ( sortLi.hasClass( 'priceAsc' ) ) {

$lis.children().sortElements(function(a, b){
return Number ($(a).find('input[name=price]').val()) > Number ($(b).find('input[name=price]').val()) ? 1 : -1;
});         

}

if ( sortLi.hasClass( 'priceDesc' ) ) {

$lis.children().sortElements(function(a, b){
return Number ($(a).find('input[name=price]').val()) < Number ($(b).find('input[name=price]').val()) ? 1 : -1;
});         

}
```

could work